# Short date format for en-CA in .net

Tags: .net, datetime

Looks like the en-CA culture in .net uses the short date format MM/dd/yy (same as en-US). Is this true? Is there a list of date formats for various cultures defined for .net

```
string date = "13/08/2008";
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}, Month: {1}, Day: {2}", dt2.Year, dt2.Month, dt2.Day);
```

This prints: "Year: 2008, Month: 8, Day: 13"

```
string date = "13/08/2008";
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-CA"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}, Month: {1}, Day: {2}", dt2.Year, dt2.Month, dt2.Day);
```

This throws: "Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Have a look at [DateTime.ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx). This explains with different cultures

Comment: As for me, short date format with "en-CA" culture applied appears as "yyyy-mm-dd".

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Please see the code examples I just added.

Comment: That's because "dd/mm/yyyy" is not valid short date format for en-CA

Comment: Is there a list of date formats for various cultures defined for .net?

Comment: @Fyodor It's really "dd/MM/yyyy" due to the leading zero on the month.  But, enumerating the culture's short dates, it *is* the short date for en-CA

Comment: @PeterRitchie interesting, thanks

Comment: Windows 7 has en-CA short date format configured by default as dd/MM/yyyy, but it changes to yyyy-MM-dd in Windows 8/10.  This can cause all kinds of problems in web application pools that handle international languages that are not congruent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's fairly easy to get the list of short date formats:

```
foreach (CultureInfo c in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", c.Name, c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
}
```

which results in the list at the bottom.  But, that's irrelevant, you're not parsing as short dates, you're parsing as general date/time.  If you want to parse short dates, do this:

```
DateTime dt2 =
    DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d",
        CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"),
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Short date formats by culture:

```
ar: dd/MM/yy
bg: d.M.yyyy 'г.'
ca: dd/MM/yyyy
zh-Hans: yyyy/M/d
cs: d.M.yyyy
da: dd-MM-yyyy
de: dd.MM.yyyy
el: d/M/yyyy
en: M/d/yyyy
es: dd/MM/yyyy
fi: d.M.yyyy
fr: dd/MM/yyyy
he: dd/MM/yyyy
hu: yyyy.MM.dd.
is: d.M.yyyy
it: dd/MM/yyyy
ja: yyyy/MM/dd
ko: yyyy-MM-dd
nl: d-M-yyyy
no: dd.MM.yyyy
pl: yyyy-MM-dd
pt: dd/MM/yyyy
rm: dd/MM/yyyy
ro: dd.MM.yyyy
ru: dd.MM.yyyy
hr: d.M.yyyy.
sk: d. M. yyyy
sq: yyyy-MM-dd
sv: yyyy-MM-dd
th: d/M/yyyy
tr: dd.MM.yyyy
ur: dd/MM/yyyy
id: dd/MM/yyyy
uk: dd.MM.yyyy
be: dd.MM.yyyy
sl: d.M.yyyy
et: d.MM.yyyy
lv: yyyy.MM.dd.
lt: yyyy.MM.dd
tg: dd.MM.yy
fa: MM/dd/yyyy
vi: dd/MM/yyyy
hy: dd.MM.yyyy
az: dd.MM.yyyy
eu: yyyy/MM/dd
hsb: d. M. yyyy
mk: dd.MM.yyyy
tn: yyyy/MM/dd
xh: yyyy/MM/dd
zu: yyyy/MM/dd
af: yyyy/MM/dd
ka: dd.MM.yyyy
fo: dd-MM-yyyy
hi: dd-MM-yyyy
mt: dd/MM/yyyy
se: dd.MM.yyyy
ga: dd/MM/yyyy
ms: dd/MM/yyyy
kk: dd.MM.yyyy
ky: dd.MM.yy
sw: M/d/yyyy
tk: dd.MM.yy
uz: dd/MM yyyy
tt: dd.MM.yyyy
bn: dd-MM-yy
pa: dd-MM-yy
gu: dd-MM-yy
or: dd-MM-yy
ta: dd-MM-yyyy
te: dd-MM-yy
kn: dd-MM-yy
ml: dd-MM-yy
as: dd-MM-yyyy
mr: dd-MM-yyyy
sa: dd-MM-yyyy
mn: yy.MM.dd
bo: yyyy/M/d
cy: dd/MM/yyyy
km: yyyy-MM-dd
lo: dd/MM/yyyy
gl: dd/MM/yyyy
kok: dd-MM-yyyy
syr: dd/MM/yyyy
si: yyyy-MM-dd
iu: d/MM/yyyy
am: d/M/yyyy
tzm: dd-MM-yyyy
ne: M/d/yyyy
fy: d-M-yyyy
ps: dd/MM/yy
fil: M/d/yyyy
dv: dd/MM/yy
ha: d/M/yyyy
yo: d/M/yyyy
quz: dd/MM/yyyy
nso: yyyy/MM/dd
ba: dd.MM.yy
lb: dd/MM/yyyy
kl: dd-MM-yyyy
ig: d/M/yyyy
ii: yyyy/M/d
arn: dd-MM-yyyy
moh: M/d/yyyy
br: dd/MM/yyyy
: MM/dd/yyyy
ug: yyyy-M-d
mi: dd/MM/yyyy
oc: dd/MM/yyyy
co: dd/MM/yyyy
gsw: dd/MM/yyyy
sah: MM.dd.yyyy
qut: dd/MM/yyyy
rw: M/d/yyyy
wo: dd/MM/yyyy
prs: dd/MM/yy
gd: dd/MM/yyyy
ar-SA: dd/MM/yy
bg-BG: d.M.yyyy 'г.'
ca-ES: dd/MM/yyyy
zh-TW: yyyy/M/d
cs-CZ: d.M.yyyy
da-DK: dd-MM-yyyy
de-DE: dd.MM.yyyy
el-GR: d/M/yyyy
en-US: M/d/yyyy
fi-FI: d.M.yyyy
fr-FR: dd/MM/yyyy
he-IL: dd/MM/yyyy
hu-HU: yyyy.MM.dd.
is-IS: d.M.yyyy
it-IT: dd/MM/yyyy
ja-JP: yyyy/MM/dd
ko-KR: yyyy-MM-dd
nl-NL: d-M-yyyy
nb-NO: dd.MM.yyyy
pl-PL: yyyy-MM-dd
pt-BR: dd/MM/yyyy
rm-CH: dd/MM/yyyy
ro-RO: dd.MM.yyyy
ru-RU: dd.MM.yyyy
hr-HR: d.M.yyyy.
sk-SK: d. M. yyyy
sq-AL: yyyy-MM-dd
sv-SE: yyyy-MM-dd
th-TH: d/M/yyyy
tr-TR: dd.MM.yyyy
ur-PK: dd/MM/yyyy
id-ID: dd/MM/yyyy
uk-UA: dd.MM.yyyy
be-BY: dd.MM.yyyy
sl-SI: d.M.yyyy
et-EE: d.MM.yyyy
lv-LV: yyyy.MM.dd.
lt-LT: yyyy.MM.dd
tg-Cyrl-TJ: dd.MM.yy
fa-IR: MM/dd/yyyy
vi-VN: dd/MM/yyyy
hy-AM: dd.MM.yyyy
az-Latn-AZ: dd.MM.yyyy
eu-ES: yyyy/MM/dd
hsb-DE: d. M. yyyy
mk-MK: dd.MM.yyyy
tn-ZA: yyyy/MM/dd
xh-ZA: yyyy/MM/dd
zu-ZA: yyyy/MM/dd
af-ZA: yyyy/MM/dd
ka-GE: dd.MM.yyyy
fo-FO: dd-MM-yyyy
hi-IN: dd-MM-yyyy
mt-MT: dd/MM/yyyy
se-NO: dd.MM.yyyy
ms-MY: dd/MM/yyyy
kk-KZ: dd.MM.yyyy
ky-KG: dd.MM.yy
sw-KE: M/d/yyyy
tk-TM: dd.MM.yy
uz-Latn-UZ: dd/MM yyyy
tt-RU: dd.MM.yyyy
bn-IN: dd-MM-yy
pa-IN: dd-MM-yy
gu-IN: dd-MM-yy
or-IN: dd-MM-yy
ta-IN: dd-MM-yyyy
te-IN: dd-MM-yy
kn-IN: dd-MM-yy
ml-IN: dd-MM-yy
as-IN: dd-MM-yyyy
mr-IN: dd-MM-yyyy
sa-IN: dd-MM-yyyy
mn-MN: yy.MM.dd
bo-CN: yyyy/M/d
cy-GB: dd/MM/yyyy
km-KH: yyyy-MM-dd
lo-LA: dd/MM/yyyy
gl-ES: dd/MM/yyyy
kok-IN: dd-MM-yyyy
syr-SY: dd/MM/yyyy
si-LK: yyyy-MM-dd
iu-Cans-CA: d/M/yyyy
am-ET: d/M/yyyy
ne-NP: M/d/yyyy
fy-NL: d-M-yyyy
ps-AF: dd/MM/yy
fil-PH: M/d/yyyy
dv-MV: dd/MM/yy
ha-Latn-NG: d/M/yyyy
yo-NG: d/M/yyyy
quz-BO: dd/MM/yyyy
nso-ZA: yyyy/MM/dd
ba-RU: dd.MM.yy
lb-LU: dd/MM/yyyy
kl-GL: dd-MM-yyyy
ig-NG: d/M/yyyy
ii-CN: yyyy/M/d
arn-CL: dd-MM-yyyy
moh-CA: M/d/yyyy
br-FR: dd/MM/yyyy
ug-CN: yyyy-M-d
mi-NZ: dd/MM/yyyy
oc-FR: dd/MM/yyyy
co-FR: dd/MM/yyyy
gsw-FR: dd/MM/yyyy
sah-RU: MM.dd.yyyy
qut-GT: dd/MM/yyyy
rw-RW: M/d/yyyy
wo-SN: dd/MM/yyyy
prs-AF: dd/MM/yy
gd-GB: dd/MM/yyyy
ar-IQ: dd/MM/yyyy
zh-CN: yyyy/M/d
de-CH: dd.MM.yyyy
en-GB: dd/MM/yyyy
es-MX: dd/MM/yyyy
fr-BE: d/MM/yyyy
it-CH: dd.MM.yyyy
nl-BE: d/MM/yyyy
nn-NO: dd.MM.yyyy
pt-PT: dd-MM-yyyy
sr-Latn-CS: d.M.yyyy
sv-FI: d.M.yyyy
az-Cyrl-AZ: dd.MM.yyyy
dsb-DE: d. M. yyyy
se-SE: yyyy-MM-dd
ga-IE: dd/MM/yyyy
ms-BN: dd/MM/yyyy
uz-Cyrl-UZ: dd.MM.yyyy
bn-BD: dd-MM-yy
mn-Mong-CN: yyyy/M/d
iu-Latn-CA: d/MM/yyyy
tzm-Latn-DZ: dd-MM-yyyy
quz-EC: dd/MM/yyyy
ar-EG: dd/MM/yyyy
zh-HK: d/M/yyyy
de-AT: dd.MM.yyyy
en-AU: d/MM/yyyy
es-ES: dd/MM/yyyy
fr-CA: yyyy-MM-dd
sr-Cyrl-CS: d.M.yyyy
se-FI: d.M.yyyy
quz-PE: dd/MM/yyyy
ar-LY: dd/MM/yyyy
zh-SG: d/M/yyyy
de-LU: dd.MM.yyyy
en-CA: dd/MM/yyyy
es-GT: dd/MM/yyyy
fr-CH: dd.MM.yyyy
hr-BA: d.M.yyyy.
smj-NO: dd.MM.yyyy
ar-DZ: dd-MM-yyyy
zh-MO: d/M/yyyy
de-LI: dd.MM.yyyy
en-NZ: d/MM/yyyy
es-CR: dd/MM/yyyy
fr-LU: dd/MM/yyyy
bs-Latn-BA: d.M.yyyy
smj-SE: yyyy-MM-dd
ar-MA: dd-MM-yyyy
en-IE: dd/MM/yyyy
es-PA: MM/dd/yyyy
fr-MC: dd/MM/yyyy
sr-Latn-BA: d.M.yyyy
sma-NO: dd.MM.yyyy
ar-TN: dd-MM-yyyy
en-ZA: yyyy/MM/dd
es-DO: dd/MM/yyyy
sr-Cyrl-BA: d.M.yyyy
sma-SE: yyyy-MM-dd
ar-OM: dd/MM/yyyy
en-JM: dd/MM/yyyy
es-VE: dd/MM/yyyy
bs-Cyrl-BA: d.M.yyyy
sms-FI: d.M.yyyy
ar-YE: dd/MM/yyyy
en-029: MM/dd/yyyy
es-CO: dd/MM/yyyy
sr-Latn-RS: d.M.yyyy
smn-FI: d.M.yyyy
ar-SY: dd/MM/yyyy
en-BZ: dd/MM/yyyy
es-PE: dd/MM/yyyy
sr-Cyrl-RS: d.M.yyyy
ar-JO: dd/MM/yyyy
en-TT: dd/MM/yyyy
es-AR: dd/MM/yyyy
sr-Latn-ME: d.M.yyyy
ar-LB: dd/MM/yyyy
en-ZW: M/d/yyyy
es-EC: dd/MM/yyyy
sr-Cyrl-ME: d.M.yyyy
ar-KW: dd/MM/yyyy
en-PH: M/d/yyyy
es-CL: dd-MM-yyyy
ar-AE: dd/MM/yyyy
es-UY: dd/MM/yyyy
ar-BH: dd/MM/yyyy
es-PY: dd/MM/yyyy
ar-QA: dd/MM/yyyy
en-IN: dd-MM-yyyy
es-BO: dd/MM/yyyy
en-MY: d/M/yyyy
es-SV: dd/MM/yyyy
en-SG: d/M/yyyy
es-HN: dd/MM/yyyy
es-NI: dd/MM/yyyy
es-PR: dd/MM/yyyy
es-US: M/d/yyyy
bs-Cyrl: d.M.yyyy
bs-Latn: d.M.yyyy
sr-Cyrl: d.M.yyyy
sr-Latn: d.M.yyyy
smn: d.M.yyyy
az-Cyrl: dd.MM.yyyy
sms: d.M.yyyy
zh: yyyy/M/d
nn: dd.MM.yyyy
bs: d.M.yyyy
az-Latn: dd.MM.yyyy
sma: yyyy-MM-dd
uz-Cyrl: dd.MM.yyyy
mn-Cyrl: yy.MM.dd
iu-Cans: d/M/yyyy
zh-Hant: d/M/yyyy
nb: dd.MM.yyyy
sr: d.M.yyyy
tg-Cyrl: dd.MM.yy
dsb: d. M. yyyy
smj: yyyy-MM-dd
uz-Latn: dd/MM yyyy
mn-Mong: yyyy/M/d
iu-Latn: d/MM/yyyy
tzm-Latn: dd-MM-yyyy
ha-Latn: d/M/yyyy
zh-CHS: yyyy/M/d
zh-CHT: d/M/yyyy*
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Interestingly, though, when I ran it, i got yyyy-MM-dd for en-CA, same as fr-CA in your list. Did it change between OS or .net versions?

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.  What OS?  What do you have set for regional settings?  I'm in Canada but I have set my settings to US for format and region...

Comment: I'm running win 8.1 and I'm in the US and use the default US for format and region.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I have the same result (.NET4.5.1/Win8.1) for en-CA. What date format is more natural for Canada actually?

Comment: The "standard" is yyyy-mm-dd... for whatever that is worth :)

Comment: Yikes. 11 years later, and dotnet is STILL telling me that my short date format is dd/MM/yyyy, even though the Canadian date standard has been yyyy-mm-dd for ... a long time now. (and I'm running Ubuntu Linux where my locale setting _definitely_ shows it as yyyy-mm-dd)